# jquery autogrow not working

Tags: jquery, autogrow

I cannot get this (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autogrowtextarea) jquery plugin to work.  below is my code.  I have checked the autogrow.js file with several other sites.  thanks.

code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test7</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="autogrow.js"></script>




</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#txtInput").autoGrow();
});
</script>


<textarea id="txtInput" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>


</body>
```

Comment: dun da dunnnn: [shameless plug](https://github.com/ultimatedelman/autogrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like jQuery itself is not included.